CMB map construction
On wiki, it has the individual band maps of CMB, which I understand has emission from the galactic plane as shown below.

But the mostly used map is the smooth one like this. How to go from the maps above to this one? How is the galactic plane emission removed? How do you disentangle the signals?


See this Don Lincoln video - Secrets of the Cosmic Microwave Background

But I mean how exactly is it subtracted? The observation in the galactic plane direction has emission from both the plane and CMB, how do you disentangle them?

The scope of this question is more like "spend the first six months of you PhD reading papers" than "get a quick answer on Stack Exchange." For example, here's a review: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.1429. Briefly, typically different foregrounds have different spectra (frequency dependence), so you can use that information to do subtraction, estimate/limit the amount of foreground, pick a good band to observe the CMB, etc.
